# Who's following up our flags?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged a post two days ago for roll-back, but no one has reviewed it yet. Because I used the "it needs ♦ moderator attention > other" option, none of our three 2K+ users can review it. Who follows up on our flags before we appoint moderators pro tempore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Community Team (of which I am a member) generally fills the role of community moderator until [pro tem moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) can be selected for your site.

We had a Community Team summit in NYC last week, so we've all been playing a bit of catch-up to pick up any tasks that might have fallen behind in our absence. Everything is just about back to normal, so hopefully there are few-if-any outstanding issues remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange community team keeps an eye on new beta sites until moderators are selected. Since they are essentially diamond moderators, they can review those flags.

If you click the number beside the "helpful flags" in your profile, you can see the pending flags and whether or not they have been declined or marked as helpful. Sometimes moderators will mark a flag as helpful even if they don't take action.

This highlights the reason why it's good to use the specific flag reasons  whenever possible. For instance, if you're flagging a post as "not an answer", or "very low quality", be sure to use those flag reasons instead so that they'll cycle through to the 2K users. Likewise, flagging as "off-topic" will also push it to 2K users.

If explanation is needed, I like to leave it in the form of a helpful comment to the poster, effectively killing 2 birds with one stone, so to speak, and I only use the "other" option when I know that the action requires someone with a diamond to intervene.

Comment: Yes, it still reads "1 waiting for review". The entry does not say "helpful" or "declined" beside it. I used the "other" option because it does not fit any other flag descriptions. I basically was requesting a rollback because I don't yet have 1K. I've never seen it take this long to review a flag, so I posted here.

Comment: If it's your post, you should be able to roll it back. If not, you could always leave a comment suggesting it be rolled back. Comments reach the widest audience possible, and give the community of 750 rep users a chance to resolve the issue, effectively removing the need for a moderator to get involved. With that said, if there's a *serious* problem with the post, where serious means it's actively harmful and may drive people away or offend them, then I'd flag it; otherwise, I'd either suggest an edit or leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Should this show up as a pending item when I click "review?" I don't keep that window open all the time, but I do check it.

Comment: I think it has to go to a moderator, not simply a 'high-rep' user.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl and GeneJ, there are some flags that you can see as 2K users, but you have to go to [tools](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tools) to see them. I [installed a Userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66724/155826) that puts the flags in the toolbar, like it does for moderators, so that I can help out on sites where I have the permissions. It's awesome! ;)